# How spark structured streaming calculate watermark

Tags: apache-spark

> However, to run this query for days, it’s necessary for the system to
>   bound the amount of intermediate in-memory state it accumulates. This
>   means the system needs to know when an old aggregate can be dropped
>   from the in-memory state because the application is not going to
>   receive late data for that aggregate any more. To enable this, in
>   Spark 2.1, we have introduced watermarking, which lets the engine
>   automatically track the current event time in the data and attempt to
>   clean up old state accordingly. You can define the watermark of a
>   query by specifying the event time column and the threshold on how
>   late the data is expected to be in terms of event time. For a specific
>   window starting at time T, the engine will maintain state and allow
>   late data to update the state until (max event time seen by the engine
>   - late threshold > T). In other words, late data within the threshold will be aggregated, but data later than the threshold will start
>   getting dropped (see later in the section for the exact guarantees).
>   Let’s understand this with an example. We can easily define
>   watermarking on the previous example using withWatermark() as shown
>   below.

Above is copied from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html.

From the above documenation description(`For a specific window starting at time T`)，it is the starting time of a given window.

I think the document is wrong, it should be the ending time of a given window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm by investigating the spark code， the document is wrong, T is the ending time of the window